# Primefaces widgetvar functions doesn't work if I submit using ajax call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to enable/disable a button based on the click of another button in my xhtml.
This doesn't work when I use ajax call but works if I disable ajax.

How do I make this work.

xhtml (this works and button is diabled for few seconds but the page loads and the button is enabled again)

```
<p:commandButton id="generateBtn" value="Generate Text"
                action="#{decisionTreeBean.generateText}" styleClass="generateBtn" widgetVar="gb"
                update=":#{p:component('decisionNotes')}" >
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton id="clearBtn" value="Clear"
                action="#{decisionTreeBean.clearText}"  styleClass="clearBtn" widgetVar="cb"
                update=":#{p:component('decisionNotes')} :#{p:component('searchForm')}" ajax="false">
            </p:commandButton>
```

xhtml(doesn't work at all)

```
<p:commandButton id="generateBtn" value="Generate Text"
                action="#{decisionTreeBean.generateText}" styleClass="generateBtn" widgetVar="gb"
                update=":#{p:component('decisionNotes')}" >
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton id="clearBtn" value="Clear"
                action="#{decisionTreeBean.clearText}"  styleClass="clearBtn" widgetVar="cb"
                update=":#{p:component('decisionNotes')} :#{p:component('searchForm')}">
            </p:commandButton>
```

Jquery

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                if (top.frames.length != 0) {
                    top.location = self.document.location;
                }
                jQuery(".clearBtn").click(function(event){
                    PF('gb').disable(); // works without ajax
                });
            });
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Your script disables the button in the browser, but if your ajax call updates the button, it will be updated enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your generateButton to your update-clause of your clearButton.

If I had to guess the reason for it working in the non-ajax version is that you actually update your site, so the generateButton receives the call that he is disabled (but then the site gets reloaded, so the state is reseted). Since you dont update that button in your ajax-version the button never gets updated, thus not disabled.

Comment: added this -  :#{p:component('generateBtn') in the update clause of clear button. Still doesn't work during ajax.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using actions instead of actionListeners? If not i would suggest switching to actionListeners. Otherwise I can only suggest to switch from your jQuery method to a boolean-variable in your backing bean and disabling it depending on that. Dont have enough knowledge about jQuery, to further help in that direction